# Error with assigning integers

Tags: c#

When I declare these integers, my code won't compile and says **Invalid token '1' in class, struct, or interface member or declaration**. Can't figure this out, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Undergraduate.BaseballSimulator
{
    class ScoreBoard
    {
        public List <Players> Players { get; }
        public SideLine ScoreKeepers { get; }

        // teams
        string home, away;

       // innings

        int 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

       // For Spectators who are curious about the teams batting average


    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign variable names: `int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8, i = 9;` or in a `List`: List<int> allNumbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

Comment: you have not assigned the int to any variable, do it this way. int a =1, b=2,c=3... etc..

Comment: how embarrassing, I can't believe I coded it like that. New to c#, decent amount of experience with c++ though. Thanks for pointing out the silly error!

Comment: @Kdrumz even in C++, you can't code like that

Answer (score 0):

Number only identifiers are not valid in c# (and perhaps any other language). For a detailed tutorial about the identifiers in c# take a look at the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx).
BTW, if you want to store those numbers you should assign them to a variable defined with a valid name and if you want to access to some consequent variables which are accessible via an index use an array or some collections. Note: in this case remember that the collections are zero-based in c#.